# Networking Algorithm to Maximum a Subset of Integers

Tags: algorithm, networking, dynamic-programming

I'm currently working on a pet project that simulates a couple different types of networks. One of them requires some specific conditions that until now I've just been brute forcing. It's not scaling well, however, so I'm trying to do this efficiently but this algorithm is really stumping me! I'll try to describe the problem as general as possible.

Given a set of integers X and an integer k, find a subset Y of X that maximizes the sum of M over each value in X:

M(s) = the largest value in Y such that it is less than or equal to s.

For example, for {2, 4, 5} and k = 2 the solution is {2, 4} with value 2+4+4=10 since M(2) = 2, M(4) = 4, and M(5) = 5.

My intuition is that the solution is a dynamic programming algorithm, but I could be way off. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a dynamic program problem with a solution - I'm not sure if it's yours because I'm not sure of the details of what you have written, but it might be.

Sort the set of numbers and draw a curve with the x axis giving the offset of the number in sorted order and the y axis giving the number. There will be some area under the curve.

You have a finite number of points, usually a smaller number than there are members of the set. You can use each of these points to mark a point of the set, and so a point of the curve.

Draw a histogram under the curve. At each marked point there is a line from that point going right, so the lines are entirely under the curve. Each such line extends till it reaches the x value for the next marked point, at which point there is a line going up to the new marked point.

The challenge is then to select which points to mark to maximize the area under the horizontal lines going right from marked points. This is straightforward dynamic programming. If you can choose up to k marked points then at each point of the histogram work out the most area you can cover to the left of that point using 0, 1, 2, ..k marked points, possibly including that point. You can work out the answer for each point by referring to the answers you have already worked out for the points to its left. The answer for the rightmost point is the answer for the entire problem.

To expand this: Suppose you are working out the best solutions for maximum area ending at offset 10. For each value j of 0..k consider taking the previous best solution ending at 0, 1, 2, 3... 9 and maintaining the height at that point, without introducing a new line. The total area for this is the area up to that point plus the new area gained by whatever height they were in at that point times the distance back to that point. Also consider doing this, but using an extra marked point at that point, so the total area is the area of the best solution with j-1 points up to e.g. point 7 plus the distance back from point 10 to point 7 times the height reached at point 7. By considering these two possibilities you can work out the best solution at point 10 using 0,1,2,...k marked points.

I think these problems are related because for each point, marked or not, the area it contributes to the histogram depends on the height of the line above it, which is the height of the largest marked point no greater that the point we are considering at the moment.

To do this you need an array of kn elements giving the area covered by the best solution at each point using at most k marked points up to there. It will also be convenient to use an extra array of this size to record the decision that led to this best solution, so you can trace the answer back. This has a cost of about kn^2, because at each of n points you need to calculate k values, and look back at all the previous points as you do so. I suspect that you could reduce this to something like O(kn) by changing the definition of what you store at each point so you never have to look back further than one previous point. If you could do that, you could economize on store at the cost of time by only storing a few intermediate points and solving the problem over again on smaller sections to trace back, but you'ld need to be desperately short of store to make that worth while.

Comment: This definitely seems like the same problem, thank you! The visual interpretation of this is really cool. I have a question about the solution. Would we need a table of nk elements or just an array of n elements? "Rightmost point" seems to suggest an array.

Comment: Also, do you have any other details for the solution? I'm still struggling to think of a recurrence relation for this. I can't figure out how the area to the left of a point can be useful to calculate the area for the next point.

Comment: I have expanded my answer to try and add more detail on this.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is very similar than the other one:

The algorithm I suggest is to start having K=N, all numbers ordered, and keep removing numbers until you reach the desired K. The number you select to remove in each step, is the one who represent the lowest loss.

Example: Let's say you have the numbers:

3, 7, 9, 13 and 19

The problem is K=3

You start in K=5 (all numbers are selected).

3 + 7 + 9 + 13 + 19 = 51

First number to remove:

if 3 is selected:
0 + 7 + 9 + 13 + 19 = 48 (we lose 3)

if 4 is selected: (7 becomes 3)
3 + 3 + 9 + 13 + 19 = 47 (we lose 4)

if 9 is selected: (9 becomes 7)
3 + 7 + 7 + 13 + 19 = 49 (we lose 2)

if 13 is selected: we lose 13 - 9 = 4

if 19 is selected: we lose 19 - 13 = 6

Lowest loss in this case is: number 9 (loss=2).

We remove 9, and then we have K=4.

For the second number to remove, we have 4 options:

if we remove 3:
0 + 7 + 7 + 13 + 19 = # (we lose 3)

if we remove 7 all 7s will become 3s:
3 + 3 + 3 + 13 + 19 = # (we lose two 7s becoming 3 = (7-3) x 2 = 8)

if we remove 13:
3 + 7 + 7 + 7 + 19 (loss = 13 - 7 = 6)

if 19 is removed:
3 + 7 + 7 + 13 + 13 (loss = 6)

Best selection here is to remove #3
and then K=3 achieving the sum: 46

I don't know if this is optimal, you could verify by comparing vs. brute force multiple cases. But, even if this is not optimal, it can give good results.

Comment: This seems like a greedy solution. Very interesting! I will try this out, thanks!